# Kinect install problems

Tags: kinect, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm following the install instructions for kinect located here:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ni#Setup_and_installation

But when I do, I get the following error at this step:

/opt/ros/cturtle/ros/core/roscpp$ rosinstall ~/ni /opt/ros/unstable 'http://www.ros.org/wiki/ni?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=ni.rosinstall'

rosinstall: command not found

I installed cturtle on linux 10.10 using the "base" installation, and ran the given command to set my environment.  Most of ros functionality seems to be working.

Does anybody know what the problem might be?

Thank you for your time,

Andy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9131/kinect-install-problems/) by [aespielberg](https://answers.ros.org/users/147/aespielberg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2011-02-19

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think rosinstall comes with the debs. See [rosinstall](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosinstall) for how to get the rosinstall tool.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2